# Annoying RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

This problem has been posted multiple times. But Android Studio is sometimes so annoyingly stupid that all of a sudden something doesn't work anymore.

I have 2 versions with EXACT SAME CODE and the other version stopped working and shows `E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout`

CLEANED. REBUILT PROJECT. INVALIDATE CACHE.

Need help with suggestions. So frustrating.

```
if (allLeadsList.isEmpty()) {
                        leadsEmptyLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        searchListLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } else {
                        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
                        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

                        leadsListAdapter = new LeadsListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), adapterOnclick, allLeadsList);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(leadsListAdapter);

                        final LayoutAnimationController controller =
                                AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(LeadHomeActivity.this, R.anim.layout_animation_down_to_up);


                        nestedScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
                                if (scrollY == v.getChildAt(0).getMeasuredHeight() - v.getMeasuredHeight()) {
                                    Constants.currentPage++;
                                    generateNextList(Constants.currentPage);
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        recyclerView.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
                        leadsListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        recyclerView.scheduleLayoutAnimation();
```

Comment: How exactly did you isolate this to an Android Studio problem? Do you have tests to verify your code is correct?

Comment: I said 2 projects with the EXACT SAME CODE. The only difference between the 2 is the app icon. All of them worked. Then suddenly, After a few days of resting, this stupid Android Studio showed error on the other version. The other one worked fine af.

Comment: So both apps have the same namespace and application Id, If they are EXACTLY SAME CODE? The error is a non-fatal log message only this would indicate your list is empty.

Comment: The log shows the response though. checking on postman as well.

Comment: So the list is populated asynchronously? Is it mutated on different threads? At evaluation it is empty then populated later  .. which could mean that depending on latency sometimes it might work whilst other time it won't, especially if the network response is cached?  You need to supply the full logic of how the list is populated.  Just initialise the recycler view and adapter with an empty list, then update the list when your network response returns. It seems you have a logic issue.